# Concept for a class with nested types

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-concepts

I'm writing a concept that requires a class to have a `ValueType` type alias and have a static function `Check` which takes `ValueType` and returns `void`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires(T object)
    {
        typename T::ValueType;
        requires (T::ValueType value)
        {
            {T::Check(value)} -> void;
        };
    };
}
```

This doesn't compile with the following error: `error: expected ')' before 'value'`.

Comment: Ahh... C++20... nice...

Comment: `requires requires` and `typename` would be the minimalistic fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution I found, which consists in splitting `Predicate` in two separate concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool HasCheck()
{
    return requires (typename T::ValueType value)
    {
        {T::Check(value)} -> void;
    };
};

template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires(T object)
    {
        typename T::ValueType;
        requires HasCheck<T>();
    };
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MHuFkDkn9R3RIS1D)

---

Alternatively, you can chain the `requires` clauses with `&&`:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires(T object)
    {
        typename T::ValueType;        
    } 
    && requires (typename T::ValueType value)
    {
        {T::Check(value)} -> void;
    };
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zzYUkHJdqpkXrMGn)

Comment: Thanks, I've also found that I don't need the `T object` part.

Answer (score 4):

you are over-compicating the problem:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate = requires(typename T::ValueType obj) {
    { T::Check(obj) } -> void;
};
```

Comment: You still need a `typename T::ValueType;` in the body if you want this to partial-order well, but +1.